# Bootstrap carousel jumps on dynamic page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, cgi, carousel

I have a page which is generated by the CGI script. And there the image jumps down, after it is shifted to the left. I have saved the HTML code of the page and stored it as new document on the server. And then it doesn't jump.

Comment: Solved: I had copied the Code for the Carousel form a tutorial. In this Code there were control-characters which are displayed as a space character in Notepad++ (even when I say display all  characters).
After removing those characters everything works as expected.